# How to scale a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have been trying to scale a text field so that it fits my screen better but I dont know how i currently have this code.

```
public class Screen extends JFrame {
private JPanel screen;
private JTextField nameField, setName;
private JButton button;

public Screen() {
    screen = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(0, 0, FlowLayout.LEADING));
    nameField = new JTextField();
    button = new JButton("Confirm");
    setName = new JTextField("Name:");

    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    setName.setEditable(false);
    setName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));

    screen.setLayout(new BoxLayout(screen, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    screen.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 5, 5, 5));

    screen.add(setName);
    screen.add(nameField);
    screen.add(button);

    this.add(screen);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(960,540));
    setTitle("My Game!!!");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
```

Comment: By "fitting" better, you mean taking all the available space ?

Answer (score 0):

```
setName = new JTextField("Name:");
```

Typically you would NOT use a JTextField that way. Instead you would use a `JLabel` to paint text that the user can't change:

```
setName = new JLabel("Name:");
```

> I have been trying to scale a text field so that it fits my screen better

All Swing components are responsible for determining their own preferred size. The layout manager can then use this information to give the component a size/location based on the rules of the layout manager.

In your case you can use:

```
//nameField = new JTextField();
nameField = new JTextField(10);
```

Now the text field will be sized to contain 10 "W" characters before the text starts to scroll. Adjust the columns value as desired.

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(960,540));
```

Don't attempt to set the preferred size of the frame. The `pack()` method will set the size of the frame based on the preferred size of all components added to the frame.

```
//setName.setEditable(false);
//setName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
```

Above statements are not needed since you will now use a JLabel and the label will determine its own size based on the text assigned to the label.